# Unexpected assertion error from Javascript and Mocha Test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm new to JavaScript and Mocha.  Given the following code:

```js
const emailClothingOfferStatus = emailClothing => {
  let withEmailClothing = {}
  const emailClothingRegex = 'hello';

  if(emailClothing){
    withEmailClothing = {validPermStatus: emailClothing}
  }

  return request
    .get(`${API_ENDPOINT}/provider`)
    .query(withEmailClothing)
    .then(
      res => {
        if (res.body.validPermStatus.match(emailClothingRegex)) {
          return {
            clothingStatus: (res.body.validPermStatus)
          }
          
         //try/catch block here
```

When I call with

```js
  const response = emailClothingOfferStatus(clothingStatus);

  return expect(response).to.eventually.equal('hello')
```

do I get the outcome of:

```js
  AssertionError: expected { clothingStatus: 'hello' } to equal 'hello'
```

Comment: Why do you expect `response` to equal `hello` when you are returning an object from the function?

Comment: @MarkMeyer That won't work because `response` is a `Promise`.

Comment: Right @Titus. I had time to edit the comment so I did.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is expecting an object to match a string, which isn't quite what you want. Your `emailClothingOfferStatus` function is returning and object with a value of 'hello'.

You should be able to fix your test by specifying what you want `response.clothingStatus` to equal (asserting against the string value):

```
      const response = emailClothingOfferStatus(clothingStatus);
      return expect(response.clothingStatus).to.eventually.equal('hello')
```

Comment: thank you. Makes sense. Your implementation now provides a 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined but I'lll work through this

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with the promise. You could re-write your original implementation to `expect(response).to.eventually.have.property('clothingStatus', 'hello'), where the second argument checks the value of the property.